# Call to undefined method App\Role::lists() in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

AdminUsersController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\Role;

    class AdminUsersController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * Display a listing of the resource.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function index()
        {
            //
    
            $users = User::all();
            return view('admin.users.index',compact('users'));
        }
    
        /**
         * Show the form for creating a new resource.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function create()
        {
            //
    
            $roles = Role::lists('name','id')->all();
            return view('admin.users.create',compact('roles'));
        }
    
    }
```

admin.users.create.php

```
<x-admin>

@section('content')

<h1>Create Users</h1>

{!!Form::open(['method'=>'POST','action'=>'AdminUsersController@store'])!!}
        
        
        <div class="form-group">
            {!!Form::label('name','Name')!!}
            {!!Form::text('name',null,['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!!Form::label('role_id','Role')!!}
            {!!Form::select('role_id',[''=>'Choose Options']+$roles,null,['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
        </div>

       

        <div class="form-group">

            {!!Form::submit('Create User',['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])!!}
        
        </div>

{!!Form::close()!!}
@endsection
</x-admin>
```

I'm trying to get the Role name in my Role Table and display to the select Role form in the admin.users.create.php but this error appears in my screen "Call to undefined method App\Role::lists() in Laravel 7" , How to fix this kind of error in Laravel 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **lists** deprecated since version **Laravel 5.2**

The `lists` method on the Collection, query builder and Eloquent query builder objects has been renamed to `pluck`.

```
$roles = Role::pluck('name', 'id');
```